# Expectation of a die roll with a coin toss

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say we throw a coin and pick a number from [0,1] uniformly. Then we roll a die, and if the coin is heads, we add the number we picked to the number on the die, otherwise we subtract it. What is the expected value of a random variable which is the output of this routine? I have an intuition that it is the same as just rolling a die but cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $C = 1$ if coin was heads, or $-1$ otherwise and your number is $u \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, and $D$ is the die roll outcome. You are looking for
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[D + Cu]
 &= \mathbb{E}[D] + \mathbb{E}[Cu] &\quad \text{by linearity of expectation}\\
 &= \mathbb{E}[D] + \mathbb{E}[C] \cdot \mathbb{E}[u]
      &\quad \text{by independence of } C,u \\
 &= \mathbb{E}[D]
\end{split}
$$
since $\mathbb{E}[C] = 0$ if the coin was fair...

Comment: First of all that looks quite logical, so thank you very much. But I get a feeling that the expected value of the coin is 0 because we define it like that. What would happen if it was defined as {0,1}? I'm sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: @sofissecondhuman if $C = 1$ if coin is heads, and $C=0$ if tails, you are not looking for $D+Cu$ anymore since if coin is tails, you should get $D-u$. In other words, we are saying you should get $D+u$ or $D-u$, whichever way you organize $C$ does not matter.

Comment: Oh now I see, thank you very much :)